# galaxy s5 recovery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, broken-screen

I have a galaxy S5, which yesterday (cracked screen) decided to go black. I can still get it to call, take pictures in the blind.

What things can I try to recover the data on here...I figured out last month that the google backups were not occuring and could not get them to backup. Was working on that when this happened.

I need my contacts, my text messages, and my photos.

I am a fairly capable sysadmin. I have googled without success. Called the Sprint store and does not sound like they are willing to help me recover the data.

Can I recover this with a blank screen and it is not rooted?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can unlock it, you can simply connect it with your computer and copy the important files (at least the photos; they're in the folder *DCIM* on your internal storage or SD card, depending on the camera settings).
You can use <s>*[Samsung Kies](http://kies.youmobile.org/)*</s> (looks like Samsung replaced it with [*"Smart Switch"*](http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/), but I haven't used it yet ... might work as well) to backup most of your other data, especially if your next phone is a Samsung as well.
To copy your text messages, you will probably need an app on your device - I don't think that Kies or Smart Switch copy them, and I don't know of any other possibility to save them by wire. I don't know if you are able to install an app (could be done via adb) and to use it blindly ...

(If you're wondering what's "adb": remove brackets:
 https[://]developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)